# How use Aplication.renderer.render from rails 5 with devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, real-time, render, warden

I want to make my app in real time

This is my error

> ActionView::Template::Error (Devise could not find the `Warden::Proxy` instance on your request environment.
>   Make sure that your application is loading Devise and Warden as expected and that the `Warden::Manager` middleware is present in your middleware stack.
>   If you are seeing this on one of your tests, ensure that your tests are either executing the Rails middleware stack or that your tests are using the `Devise::Test::ControllerHelpers` module to inject the `request.env['warden']` object for you.)
>   1: -if user_signed_in?
>   2:   .ui.popup.computer{id:"post#{post.id}user#{post.user.id}", style:"padding:0px"}
>   3:     .ui.card
>   4:       .image

I don't know what to do

Help me please.

Comment: I haven't found proper solution yet, but here's some links FYI: https://evilmartians.com/chronicles/new-feature-in-rails-5-render-views-outside-of-actions , http://www.thegreatcodeadventure.com/using-action-controller-renderers-in-rails-5-with-devise/

Answer (score 7):

I think I found a solution for my case.

Define `renderer_with_signed_in_user` class method in `ApplicationController`.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  ...
  def self.renderer_with_signed_in_user(user)
    ActionController::Renderer::RACK_KEY_TRANSLATION['warden'] ||= 'warden'
    proxy = Warden::Proxy.new({}, Warden::Manager.new({})).tap { |i|
      i.set_user(user, scope: :user, store: false, run_callbacks: false)
    }
    renderer.new('warden' => proxy)
  end
  ...
end
```

And then you can render from other parts of Rails app, like this:

```
renderer = ApplicationController.renderer_with_signed_in_user(user)
renderer.render template: 'notifications/show', layout: false, locals: { foo: 'bar' }
```

Credit to *Stefan Wienert* for his [article](https://www.stefanwienert.de/blog/2016/04/05/using-rails-5-new-renderer-with-authentication-gems-like-clearance-or-devise/)

Answer (score -1):

When you use the new Rails 5 Application Renderer, no middleware is executed.
Devise uses Warden and set it as an environnement variable env['warden'], and thus it is missing when you call renderer.
That's the reason why you get this error.

To make it work, in your controller simply use before_action for the controller#action that will be rendered to set and pass the instance variable you need to the view.

If you need to check if user is logged in, or use current_user in the rendered view:

```
class ExamplesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :user_logged_in?, only: :show
  before_action :set_user, only: :show

def show
   # whatever the action does
end

private
  def user_logged_in?
    @user_logged_in = user_signed_in?
  end

  def set_user
    @user = current_user
  end
end
```

Then in the view ExamplesController#show :

```
# views/examples/show.html.erb

<%= "Online" if @user_logged_in %>
<%= @user.full_name %>
```

Hope that helps

Comment: I think the questioner's problem comes from that trying to render templates outside controller.